# $ is not defined

Tags: javascript

Когда пишу в консоль браузера свой код, все работает отлично, а при интеграции кода в расширение выводит ошибку. Такое ощущение что сначала запускается расширение, а потом библиотеки, хотя я пробовал добавить библиотеки и в само расширение, не помогло.

Comment: Каким образом вы пробовали добавлять библиотеки в расширение?

Comment: через манифест.

Comment: А в манифест вы добавил перед своим файлом ?

Comment: да конечно! но почему то все еще не получается решить данную проблему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в консоли дуоступны переменные страницы, а из расширения - нет. Если на странице определена переменная `$`, она и будет использоваться.

Во-вторых, в консоли у `$` есть особое значение.

Напиши в консоли

```
$
```

И посмотри результат.

Из наиболее распространённых вариантов:

1. jQuery

   ```
   function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
   ```
2. Особая обёртка над `document.querySelector`, доступная только в консоли:

   ```
   function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
   ```

Comment: `function(n,t){return t?t.querySelector.call(t,n):window.document.querySelector.apply(window.document,arguments)}` - ослик

Comment: @ReinRaus, упс.. Я неправ. Всё-таки селектор.

Comment: Все спасибо большое, нужно было скопировать присвоение переменной с сайты в моё расширение

Answer (score 3):

Переменная `$` обычно объявляется известной библиотекой JQuery. Видимо при тестировании в консоли вы это делали из открытой страницы, с подключенной библиотекой JQuery. Код расширения работает в отдельной от текущей страницы среде и не может пользоваться никаким кодом, находящимся на странице, в том числе и подключенными библиотеками.

Если вам нужен функционал, предоставляемый какими либо библиотеками, например JQuery, подключите эти библиотеки явно внутрь вашего расширения. Например добавьте их в проект и опишите в manifest.json для расширения chrome, или похожими способами для расширений других браузеров.

В крайнем случае попробуйте сам текст библиотеки добавить непосредственно в начало кода вашего расширения.

Так же посмотрите для примера исходный код известного расширения adBlock, оно использует JQuery и включает в себя эту библиотеку.

Comment: Мимо. Скорее всего.

Comment: попробовал я добавить в сам файл где мой код и даже так выскакивает одна и та же ошибка

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, разобрался